# TypeScript Argument of type 'IAttachmentInfo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<File[]> Which Type to use?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to update an array so I can submit it to a sharepoint list. The array is of multiple file attachments. I'm using sp pnp to retrieve and submit the files. I can delete the files on the app, but when it submits it won't update the files. I know why:

Here is the state:

```
import { IAttachmentInfo } from "@pnp/sp/attachments";
import { IItem } from "@pnp/sp/items/types

 const [fileAttachmentsToUpload, setFileAttachmentsToUpload] = useState<Array<File>>(null);
 const [attachedFilesRetrieved, setAttachedFilesRetrieved] = useState<Array<IAttachmentInfo>>(null);
```

I use `attachedfilesRetrieved` to get the files:

```
const getAttachedFiles = () => {
        Utils
            .ReadListItem("MyList", Id)
            .then(item => {
                item.attachmentFiles
                  .get()
                  .then(setAttachedFilesRetrieved);
         });
  };
```

This to change the files:

```
const setFileUploadEventHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {

        let resultFile = event.target.files;
        if (resultFile) {
            console.log(resultFile);
            let fileInfos: Array<File> = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < resultFile.length; i++) {

                let file: File = resultFile[i];
                fileInfos.push(file);

            }
            setFileAttachmentsToUpload(fileInfos);
        }
    };
```

And attempting this to delete the files and finally make the changes on an update:

```
const _deleteAttachedFile = (ev: number) => {
        let fileArray = attachedFilesRetrieved;
        const sid = ev;
        console.log(fileArray, 'fileArray of fileAttachments');
    
        fileArray.splice(sid, 1);

        setFileAttachmentsToUpload(fileArray);
     
    };
```

I'm getting this red error on `setFileAttachmentsToUpload`:

```
Argument of type 'IAttachmentInfo[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<File[]>'.
  Type 'IAttachmentInfo[]' is not assignable to type 'File[]'
```

My onupdate function has to use:

```
  props.onUpdate(request, fileAttachmentsToUpload);
```

As you can see I'm using one state to retrieve the files to display them on the app, and another to submit them. The problem is the Types and TypeScript and me not knowing which type to use!

Comment: `IAttachmentInfo` is not a TypeScript type, it's a type of your own. Please add its declaration to your question.

Comment: Sorry, added. I'm using sp PNP library.

Answer (score 1):

Here you set `fileArray` to point to `attachedFilesRetrieved`, which you had typed as `IAttachmentInfo[]`:

```
let fileArray = attachedFilesRetrieved; 
// attachedFilesRetrieved is of type IAttachmentInfo[],
// so fileArray is too
```

Then you feed that to `setFileAttachmentsToUpload`, which you typed to be a setState function that expects `File[]`:

```js
setFileAttachmentsToUpload(fileArray);
// fileArray is of type IAttachmentInfo[], but setFileAttachmentsToUpload
// expects an argument of type File[]
```

Its easy to see why typescript is complaining.

Comment: What to do then? Which type to use?

Comment: I've added to my initial question title to ask which Type to use. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that my code elsewhere was not using the correct Type. The correct Type was `IAttachmentFileInfo` when trying to update files, this type caters for multiple files. Whereas when I needed to read files from SharePoint, I had to use `IAttachmentInfo`. It was difficult because I had to convert the array from `IAttachmentFileInfo` Type:

```
const _deleteAttachedFile = (selectedFileId: number) => {
        let selectedFile: IAttachmentInfo = attachedFilesRetrieved[selectedFileId];
        let selectedFileInfo: IAttachmentFileInfo = {
            name: selectedFile.FileName,
            content:null
        }
        setFilesToBeRemoved([...filesToBeRemoved, selectedFileInfo]);
```